# Mechanism for decarboxylation

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds

Propose a mechanism for the following transformation.

[image]

I gather that this mechanism might be similar to decarboxylation of keto acids: 
[image]

However, I am unsure of how to begin.

Comment: first, addition of water will occur at the ester to form a carboxylic acid which will then be removed after heating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In acidic media, the ester carbonyl will be protonated and the carbonyl carbon attacked by a water molecule. The intermediate will have a proton abstracted by a water molecule and the ethoxy group will be protonated (it can happen either by intermolecular reaction with an H3O+ or by an intramolecular reaction with a proton migration from the protonated intermediate after the water attack). The carbonyl is restored and an ethanol molecule leaves the structure. A subsequent proton abstraction by water forms the carboxylic acid, which will then suffer decarboxylation following the mechanism you presented above. (I'm sorry about my ChemDraw, I suck at drawing even on a computer).

[image: Reaction]